# Recording simple offline contribution

Tags: civicontribute, drupal

I'm using CiviCRM with Drupal to develop an internal (non-public) donor management system. Everything was coming together nicely until I began trying to create a simple block to record an offline donation from an existing contact (ie: receiving a check or cash). My intent was to have the simplest block possible (ie: amount, date received, optional check number, and a submit button).

I've Googled the heck out of it but just can't seem to make any progress. If this is indeed possible, anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using Webform + Webform civicrm + webform block modules?

Comment: Doesn't offer payment method or check number etc afaik

Comment: I took another crack at Webform + Webform CiviCRM and it looks like I can get pretty close.  I can definitely record the amount of the contribution but I need to be able to set the "receive date" to something other than today. 

The "receive date" is not one of the fields exposed by Webform CIviCRM but the documentation has a section called "Anatomy of a Form Key" which seems to indicate that creating a date field with a key of "civicrm_1_contribution_1_contribution_receive_date" would work.  Unfortunately, it still populates with today's date.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the batch operations. They are designed for you to enter multiple contributions at the same time and therefore will allow the data to be captured as you want. You should find the ability to create batches under your contributions menu.

Comment: i think the goal is a block, similar to 'New Contribution' but stripped down to only a few fields.. i checked afform and can't see it is yet possible